# Magneto 2- remove default checkbox for same shipping and billing address

Tags: magento2

As there are alot of question regarding same and also have verified answers too, but it not solving my issue as ,I want to remove default  check from that from on checkout page , I am using Amasty one page checkout
Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: You can try this solution here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/236452/101754

Comment: @LitCommerceExpert I tried this solution too it didn't work for me.

Comment: Can you share your code? I need to know what you've done so I can continue to find solutions to your problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overwrite:

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/billing-address.html

in your custom theme:

> app/design/frontend///Magento_Checkout/web/template/billing-address.html

And remove:

```
<div class="billing-address-same-as-shipping-block field choice" data-bind="visible: canUseShippingAddress()">
    <input type="checkbox" name="billing-address-same-as-shipping"
           data-bind="checked: isAddressSameAsShipping, click: useShippingAddress, attr: {id: 'billing-address-same-as-shipping-' + getCode($parent)}"/>
    <label data-bind="attr: {for: 'billing-address-same-as-shipping-' + getCode($parent)}"><span
            data-bind="i18n: 'My billing and shipping address are the same'"></span></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

My Magento Version is 2.4

instead of overriding core js file I use Js Mixin way for achieve output see below image.

> create Vendor\Module\view\frontend\web\js\view\checkout\billing-address-mixin.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'underscore',
    'uiRegistry',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
], function (
    $,
    ko,
    _,
    registry,
    quote,
    ) {
    'use strict';

    var mixin = {
        
        /**
         * on change billing address set `isAddressSameAsShipping` variable as a "false" for display Edit Button below the Address 
         * 
         * see /Magento_Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/billing-address/details.html template file 
         */
        initObservable: function () {
            var result = this._super();

            quote.billingAddress.subscribe(function (newAddress) {
                this.isAddressSameAsShipping(false);
            }, this);

            return result;
        },

        /**
         * return false for hide the `My billing and shipping address are the same` checkbox 
         * 
         * see /Magento_Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/billing-address.html template file
         */
        canUseShippingAddress: ko.computed(function () {
            return false;
        }),

    }

    return function (target) {
        return target.extend(mixin);
    };
});
```

& then create `Vendor\Module\view\frontend\requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {         
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/billing-address': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/view/checkout/billing-address-mixin': true
            },
        }
    },
}
```

**OUTPUT:-**

[image: Output Image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in the Amasty One Step Checkout 4.2.0 admin settings.

There is a 'Design' section in the settings that gives you this setting:
['Billing and Shipping Address are the same' by default drop down menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qJVD.png)

Set as desired. Clear your Cache Management:

1. Configuration and
2. Page Cache

Reload the page to see the change.